# Text renders strangely in Safari when using columns

Tags: safari

I am working on this site: http://www.diewebgestaltung.at/kliweb2/marken/

As soon as I use CSS columns (column-count: 2; column-gap: 40px; column-rule: 1px dotted $hellgrau;), the text looks strangely bold in Safari. It should be the same weight as in the 1-column introduction. The CSS font definition is the same.

I searched the forum and tried -webkit-font-smoothing and text-rendering in CSS, but none of it worked.

Any ideas?

THANKS